# React-Redux: How do I populate a component's prop on load with data from an async call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-redux

I have this autocomplete component that takes an array of terms as a dataSource prop. The data I want to feed in resides in a public API, and I've followed the tutorial [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) to get to the code below. But this tutorial (and many others out there) explain how to bind these actions to an event, whereas I want to populate this prop with data on page load. How would I go about doing that?

**actions.js**

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

export function loadSchools(termId) {
  return {
    type: 'LOAD_SCHOOLS',
    termId
  };
}

export function receiveSchools(termId, json) {
  return {
    type: 'RECEIVE_SCHOOLS',
    termId,
    schools: json.data.children.map(child => child.data), // ???
    receivedAt: Date.now()
  };
}

export function getSchools(termId) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(loadSchools(termId));
    return fetch('http://www.northwestern.edu/class-descriptions/4650/index-v2.json')
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
          throw new Error('Bad response from server');
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => dispatch(receiveSchools(termId, data)));
  };
}
```

**reducers.js**

```
const initialState = {
  schoolsData: {
    isFetching: false,
    lastUpdated: 0,
    schools: []
  }
};

function schools(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOAD_SCHOOLS':
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true
      };
    case 'RECEIVE_SCHOOLS':
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        schools: action.schools,
        lastUpdated: receivedAt
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default schools;
```

**Search.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import AutoComplete from 'material-ui/AutoComplete';

export default class Search extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <AutoComplete
          hintText="Search for something."
          dataSource={this.props.searchdata}
          maxSearchResults={15}
          filter={AutoComplete.caseInsensitiveFilter}
          onNewRequest={}
        />
    );
  }
}

Search.propTypes = {
  searchdata: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  onSelect: React.PropTypes.func
};
```

**index.jsx**

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import { grey500, white, fullBlack } from 'material-ui/styles/colors';
import { fade } from 'material-ui/utils/colorManipulator';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import schools from './reducers/reducers';
import colors from './colors';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar.jsx';
import Serif from './components/Serif.jsx';

const store = createStore(schools, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware));

const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary1Color: colors.northwesternPurple,
    primary2Color: colors.northwesternPurple120,
    primary3Color: grey500,
    accent1Color: colors.northwesternPurple30,
    accent2Color: colors.richBlack10,
    accent3Color: colors.richBlack50,
    textColor: colors.richBlack80,
    alternateTextColor: white,
    canvasColor: white,
    borderColor: colors.richBlack20,
    disabledColor: fade(colors.richBlack80, 0.3),
    pickerHeaderColor: colors.northwesternPurple,
    clockCircleColor: fade(colors.richBlack80, 0.07),
    shadowColor: fullBlack
  }
});

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
          <div> {/* MuiThemeProvider requires stricly one child element */}
            <NavBar />
            <Serif /> {/* This component contains SearchContainer, which in turn contains Search */}
          </div>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can render your **Search** component from another component, let's call it **SearchContainer**. **SearchContainer** is decorated by the [connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) function from [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) that has as only role to dispatch the action to fetch the schools. **SearchContainer** doesn't render **Search** component until the school are fetched.

Here an example of what the code would look like. Here I assume you don't use [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux).

First you have a small problem in your initial state in **reducers.js**. It should be:

```
const initialState = {
  isFetching: false,
  lastUpdated: 0,
  schools: []
};

function schools(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOAD_SCHOOLS':
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true
      };
    case 'RECEIVE_SCHOOLS':
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        schools: action.schools,
        lastUpdated: receivedAt
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**SearchContainer.js**

```
// ./containers/SearchContainer.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { loadSchools } from '../actions/actions'
import Search from '../components/Search';

class SearchContainer extends Component { 
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadSchools(this.props.termId);
  },
  render() {
    const { 
      schools, 
      isFetching
    } = this.props;
    if (isFetching) {
      return null;
    }
    return <Search schools={schools} />;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isFetching: state.isFetching,
  schools: state.schools
});

const mapActionsToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  loadSchools: (termId) => dispatch(loadSchools(termId)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(SearchContainer);
```

In this way, at the first render, your Search component is not rendered. It is rendered, only after the schools are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can dispatch the LOAD_SCHOOLS action from the *componentDidMount* lifecycle method (maybe in your *Serif* component but I can't see the code for that).

From the docs:

*componentDidMount()* is invoked immediately after a component is mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, *this is a good place to instantiate the network request*. Setting state in this method will trigger a re-rendering.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: Is it really as easy as calling store.dispatch()? I thought the "correct way" using redux would involve some complex way of using the connect() function.

Comment: If you are using connect then you'll probably not be using the component lifecycle methods, however I don't see any reason not to use store.dispatch directly to seed your data on component load, then using connect for all your other component hook ups.

Comment: And hopefully the 'correct' way should never promote a more 'complex' way of doing things! :-)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Joonpark13/419bb60a0c989f8270f67f34bd36b043 This is my new Search.jsx and the console did log 'dispatched' but I'm getting an empty prop for dataSource when I view it in the React inspector.

Comment: Hi Joon - I had a look at your code and although you are dispatching the action your components still need to subscribe to changes in the store so that they can re-render when it changes. This is where connect comes in; so you will still have to use connect as you were to hook up your components (or do it manually using subscribe).